# React and d3.js - create Play/Pause button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am working on a bar racing chart in React using d3.js library. I implemented [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/building-racing-bar-chart-in-d3js-d89b71cd3439) example, but I am not able to add a Play/Pause function to stop and resume the animation without re-rendering the whole chart.
Here is my code:

```
export default function RacerBar(){
    const ref = useRef()
    const [animationEnabled, setAnimationEnabled] = useState(true);
    const [isFetched, setIsFetched] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState([{}]);
    const [selectedIndicator, setSelectedIndicator] = useState("indicator_1");
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchData = async () => {
            await fetch("/api/chart").then(
                res => res.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                        setData(data)
                        setIsFetched(true)
                    })
        }
        fetchData()
    },[])
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (isFetched) {
            const names = new Set(data.map(d => d.client))
            const datavalues = Array.from(d3.rollup(data, ([d]) => d[selectedIndicator], d => +d.year, d => d.client))
            const svg = d3.select(ref.current)
            svg.selectAll("*").remove()
            //other svg settings
            const ticker = 2500;
            
            async function plotChart(data) {        
                    const dateList = new Set(data.map(d=>d.year));
                    const fontSize = 16;
                    const rectProperties = {height: 20, padding: 10}
                    const container = svg.append("g")
                                            .classed("container", true)
                                            .style("transform", "translateY(25px)")
                    const widthScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                    const axisTop = svg
                                    .append('g')
                                    .classed('axis', true)
                                    .style("transform", "translate(10px, 20px)")
                                    .call(d3.axisTop(widthScale))
                    
                    //This part is responsible for the animation. 
                    const update = (date) =>  {
                        const presentData = [];
                        for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                            if (data[i].year === date){
                                var key=data[i].client;
                                var value = data[i][selectedIndicator]
                                presentData.push({"key": key, "value": value})
                            }
                        }
                        
                        //svg maniplation, drawing bars and labels similar to the example
                            
                    }
                    // iterating through the data
                    for (const date of dateList) {
                        update(date)    
                        await new Promise(done => setTimeout(() => done(), ticker));
                    } 
                }
                plotChart(data)
        }
    },[isFetched, selectedIndicator])
    
    
    const handleIndicatorChange = (event) => {
        setSelectedIndicator(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div className="RacerBar">
            <Dropdown label="Chooes option"
                options={dropDownItems}
                value={selectedIndicator}
                onChange={handleIndicatorChange}/>
            <div className="container">
                <svg
                    ref={ref}  
                    style={{width: parseInt(width, 10) || 1000, 
                        height: parseInt(height, 10) || 1000}}
                    id={`racerbar_chart`}
                />
            </div>  
            <Button
                onClick={() => { setAnimationEnabled(!animationEnabled) }}>
                    {animationEnabled ? "Pause" : "Play"}
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is a small explanation:

I have to wait until the data has fetched. I used useEffect for this purpose. This slice of the code works well.

When fetching is finished another useEffect has been triggered that calls the plotChart function.
The first part of this function makes further manipulation on svg object then comes the updater function. This part is responsible for drawing bars, creating labels etc.

This updater function is called by a for cycle that iterates through the data end updates the chart.
I tried multiple possibilities, but I am not able to find an appropriate solution to isolate updater function and calling that through useEffect.

Needless to say, but I am a beginner in React, and I do not understand its DOM management completely.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT

Thanks to help of D.B.K. I could find an acceptable solution of my problem. I uploaded the final code on my [Github](https://github.com/abigel87/react_d3/blob/main/racerBar.js) page, feel free to view or comment it.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Where is `selectedIndicator` declared?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am sorry but when I tried to reduce my code accidentally I deleted it.
I declared it with a setState function at the beginning of the code.
I also forgot to mention that the code is working well, it is animating the chart but when I changed the indicator, of course, it re-render the whole chart.

Comment: Just remove `selectedIndicator` from the useEffect dependency array, and it should not re-render everytime it changes

Comment: Thank you!
Of course, you are right, but my goal is to stop or restart the iteration without re-rendering the SVG object. To active this, i think, I suppose to modify the second useEffect function.

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting out the `plotChart` function out, and call it in a separate `useEffect` like this?

```js
export default function RacerBar() {
  const ref = useRef()
  const [animationEnabled, setAnimationEnabled] = useState(true);
  const [isFetched, setIsFetched] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([{}]);
  const [selectedIndicator, setSelectedIndicator] = useState("indicator_1");
  async function plotChart(data, selectedIndicator) {
    const svg = d3.select(ref.current)
    const dateList = new Set(data.map(d => d.year));
    const fontSize = 16;
    const rectProperties = { height: 20, padding: 10 }
    const container = svg.append("g")
      .classed("container", true)
      .style("transform", "translateY(25px)")
    const widthScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    const axisTop = svg
      .append('g')
      .classed('axis', true)
      .style("transform", "translate(10px, 20px)")
      .call(d3.axisTop(widthScale))

    //This part is responsible for the animation. 
    const update = (date) => {
      const presentData = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].year === date) {
          var key = data[i].client;
          var value = data[i][selectedIndicator]
          presentData.push({ "key": key, "value": value })
        }
      }

      //svg maniplation, drawing bars and labels similar to the example

    }
    // iterating through the data
    for (const date of dateList) {
      update(date)
      await new Promise(done => setTimeout(() => done(), ticker));
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await fetch("/api/chart").then(
        res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setData(data)
          setIsFetched(true)
        })
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFetched) {
      const names = new Set(data.map(d => d.client))
      const datavalues = Array.from(d3.rollup(data, ([d]) => d[selectedIndicator], d => +d.year, d => d.client))
      const svg = d3.select(ref.current)
      svg.selectAll("*").remove()
      //other svg settings
      const ticker = 2500;
    }
  }, [isFetched])

  useEffect(() => {
    plotChart(data, selectedIndicator);
  }, [data, selectedIndicator])


  const handleIndicatorChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedIndicator(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="RacerBar">
      <Dropdown label="Chooes option"
        options={dropDownItems}
        value={selectedIndicator}
        onChange={handleIndicatorChange} />
      <div className="container">
        <svg
          ref={ref}
          style={{
            width: parseInt(width, 10) || 1000,
            height: parseInt(height, 10) || 1000
          }}
          id={`racerbar_chart`}
        />
      </div>
      <Button
        onClick={() => { setAnimationEnabled(!animationEnabled) }}>
        {animationEnabled ? "Pause" : "Play"}
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my absence! You answer helped me a lot to solve the problem. I edited my original question and inserted a link to my final solution. Many thanks again!